# Missing Java SDK. Please make sure Java SDK is on your PATH in TITANIUM STUDIO,

Tags: android, titanium-alloy

Getting the below error when trying to run sample **Alloy**(Android titanium).

I have already done these thigs :-

set `JAVA_HOME`,`JDK_HOME`,`PATH`,

WORKING ENVIRONMENT ARE :-  **OS -            WIN 8, 
                            Titanium SDK - 3.1.3.GA
                             CLI version 3.1.2**,
                              **JAVA - CHECKED WITH 1.7.0, AND 1.6**

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.2, Titanium SDK version 3.1.3.GA
[ERROR] :  "Missing Java SDK. Please make sure Java SDK is on your PATH
Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, and solved it by installing [the Java JDK from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and then adding then adding the resulting `bin path` to my `PATH` environment variable ("C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin", for me).